# How do I autowire based on the generic type?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've a spring application that deals with two types of objects - orders and faults. Most of the processing is same for both type of objects, but they are queried from different tables. So, I've done something like this

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    private final Processor<Order> orderProcessor;
    private final Processor<Fault> faultProcessor;

    public MyService(Processor<Order> orderProcessor, Processor<Fault> faultProcessor) {
        this.orderProcessor = orderProcessor;
        this.faultProcessor = faultProcessor;
    }
    
    public void process(Map<String, List<BaseEntity>> input) {
        
        orderProcessor.process(input.get("ORDERS"));
        faultProcessor.process(input.get("FAULTS"));
    }
}
```

And my Processor implementation looks like

```
@Service
public class Processor<U extends BaseEntity> {

    private final BaseRespository<U> repository;

    public Processor(BaseRespository<U> repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void process() {
        //query the repository and do something
    }
}
```

And my repositories are

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T extends BaseEntity> extends CrudRepository<T, Key> {
    @Transactional
    List<T> findAll(String id);
}

@Repository("order")
public interface OrderRepository extends BaseRepository<Order> {}

@Repository("fault")
public interface FaultRepository extends BaseRepository<Fault> {}
```

However, when I start the application, it fails saying "Constructor of Processor required a single bean but two were found". What could be the issue here?
I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.0 / Spring 5.3.2

Comment: I'm not sure what you want will in fact be possible. It's important to understand that generic types in Java are a compile-time only feature. When your code actually runs, all generic types are erased. If you come from C++ and expected them to work like templates this may surprise you. Spring can't differentiate one Processor bean from another if their only difference is a template argument. You should make separate Processor beans for each object type like you did for BaseRepository.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`@Qualifier` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html).

```java
@Service
public class MyService {
    private final Processor<Order> orderProcessor;
    private final Processor<Fault> faultProcessor;

    public MyService(@Qualifier("order") Processor<Order> orderProcessor, @Qualifier("fault") Processor<Fault> faultProcessor) {
        this.orderProcessor = orderProcessor;
        this.faultProcessor = faultProcessor;
    }
    
    public void process(Map<String, List<BaseEntity>> input) {
        
        orderProcessor.process(input.get("ORDERS"));
        faultProcessor.process(input.get("FAULTS"));
    }
}
```

The annotation tells Spring to use the `Repository` with the named supplied in the `@Qualifer` annotation.  Since you annotated your `orderRepository` with `@Repository("order")`, then `@Qualifier("order")` will tell Spring to use that repository.

---

## EDIT

Spring, like anything else in Java, can't assign an interface to an interface.  For example, the following code won't compile

```java
private List<String> stringList = new List<String>();
```

This is because the instantiated value must be a valid implementation.
You can fix this using further abstraction, and/or design patterns.  Take a look at the [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and/or the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to get an idea of how to implement them more effectively.  Alternatively, you could try something like this using a provider to handle the process request internally.

##### New Supports Interface

```java
public interface Processes<T>
{
  boolean processes(T object);
}
```

##### Processor

```java
@Service
public abstract class Processor<U extends BaseEntity> implements Processes<Object>
{
  public abstract void process(U entity);
}
```

##### Implementation

```java
@Service
public class OrderProcessor extends Processor<Order>
{
  @Qualifier("order")
  BaseRepository<Order> repository;

  public OrderProcessor(BaseRepository<Order> repository)
  {
    this.repository = repository;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Object object)
  {
    return object instanceof Order;
  }

  @Override
  public void process(Order order)
  {
    /// ... do process stuff
  }
}
```

#### Spring Autowired List with Provider

```java
@Service
public static class ProcessorProvider
{
  @Autowired
  List<Processor<? extends BaseEntity>> processors;

  public <T extends BaseEntity> void process(T type)
  {
    var processor = processors.stream().filter(proc -> proc.processes(type)).findFirst();

    processor.ifPresent(proc -> process(proc, type));
  }

  private <T extends BaseEntity> void process(Processor<? extends BaseEntity> processor, T type)
  {
    if (processor instanceof OrderProcessor) {
      ((OrderProcessor) processor).process((Order) type);
    }
    else if (processor instanceof FaultProcessor) {
      ((FaultProcessor) processor).process((Fault) type);
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can call the ProcessorProvider from your implementing code

```java
@Service
public class MyService {
  
  SpringscratchApplication.ProcessorProvider provider;

  public MyService(SpringscratchApplication.ProcessorProvider provider) {
    this.provider = provider;
  }

  public void process(Map<String, List<BaseEntity>> input) {

    input.get("ORDERS").forEach(order -> provider.process(order));
    input.get("FAULTS").forEach(order -> provider.process(order));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried with that already, I'm still getting the same error. In addition IntelliJ complains that "Could not autowire. Qualified bean must be of 'Processor<Order>' type.

Guess, the qualifiers will work only in scenarios where I have two processor implementations and not for cases where I need to qualify the repository variable inside that object that is being initialized (i.e. processor)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I apparently misunderstood your question when I first read it.  I will edit my answer.